# wordpress blog site transfaring http:// to https://?

Tags: wordpress, https

i have wordpress Blog site currently this site working on http it work fine but when try to open in https at that time whole site broken
main domain is work in https:// blog site is working in http://
what to do transferring my blog site http:// to https://

Comment: did you purchased ssl? for the wordpress blog

Comment: yes, it work fine in main site but my blog site not working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to setup a wordpress site from http to https do this steps:

1. Go to Settings -> General
2. Change WordPress Adress & Site Adress from http to to https
3. add a redirect to your .htaccess file (apache server)

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   </IfModule>
4. add this to your wp-config.php `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`
5. log in to your wp-admin and install this plugin: [better search and replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)
6. after plugin activation go to Tools -> better search and replace
7. search for: http://yourdomain.com replace with: https://yourdomain.com
8. select all tables
9. uncheck "Run as dry run?" and click the "run" button
10. you're done!

Just a notice:
to have a backup is recommended

Answer (score 0):

Once you purchase SSL for your site, use define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); OR define('FORCE_SSL', true); in wp-config file.

Comment: i try this but whole site is broken